# Script for measuring runtime

Tags: time, runtime, elki

If I run an algorithm in an environment (ELKI) and want to measure the time, how can I do that?
 - Make a script? -let that run 10 seconds and press the run button in the environment to run the algorithm - and subtract the 10 seconds.
 - or maybe I can make a script that interacts with ELKI and knows when I press the run algorithm-button (But I can't see how)
 - How do one usually write a script? In what language? Can you link to a page, where I can learn it? Bash-script? Perl? Python?

Thanks for any respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-time` option. Do **not** enable `-verbose` as this will usually slow down the process due to output of progress logging. You may also want to set  `-resulthandler DiscardResultHandler`.

ELKI also has a command line mode for scripting. The logging window always shows a command line parameters you have set.